# Как сохранять и отправлять Cookies в Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin

На стороне сервера(php)  я открываю сессию и её id записывается в Cookies. Как при запросе к другому скрипту на сервере использовать этот id, записанный в Cookies? То есть, нужно хранить Cookies на устройстве и при каждом запросе отправлять их на сервер?

Comment: cookies придуманы для браузеров, как я понимаю у вас речь о API. Передавайте как-то иначе. Это мое личное мнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно печеньки - могу рекомендовать библиотеку

https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar

Она все за вас сделает. вам же только ее подключить к проекту и воткнуть в okhttp клиент.
И да не забудьте в тех запросах, где вы получаете НОВЫЕ куки (при авторизации к примеру) перезапустить retrofit клиент, что бы новые куки успешно применились